# How to manage in RASA an unique user_id for many channels in parallel?

Tags: authentication, uuid, connector, rasa-core, rasa

I have to design an e-learning tutorbot that has multiple possible channels living in parallel:

1. A **live chat** (to support learner with FAQ when browsing the e-learning application website)
2. A **IM chat** as Telegram (for asyncronous notifications)
3. An **email** (for anything else)
4. ...

Take a part the connectors gateway communication logics.

**My problem/question is mainly about how to manage user identification.** 
I want that a user is identified with an unique identifier (call it `conversation_id`) regardless of channel.

In the mentioned scenario user has one different ID for each channel:

1. An `account_id` on the website (e.g. `solyarisoftware`)
2. A `chat_id` on Telegram (e.g. `1234567890`)
3. An `email_address` (e.g. `giorgio.robino@blabla.com`)

So, how to let RASA chatbot accept requests coming from the **same user** (but from different channels)? In other words, how can I map multiple channel IDs into a RASA unique ID, say the `conversation_id` ?

At the end of the day I need to generate a lookup table that map a UUID with all channel ids. Right?

**But is not clear to me what's a good (simple) user experience.** At first glance seems to me that that I need a sort of login/registration flow: each time user submit a request on channel X, only for the first time, the user must  identify himself somewhere (with his email/account_id?). So by example trough Telegram, when the Telegram connector server receive a `/start` command, the bot must ask the user email(or account_id), to be able to associate 1-to-1 the TG `chat_id` with that email. Not perfect in terms of security, I admit.

Any experience/idea/suggestion?

Thanks/giorgio

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an hands-on experience on this but it is something I have been thinking myself for a while.

Indeed the 'merge' of the different accounts (across channels) is something that we need to maintain ourselves, making sure each channel user ID is eventually mapped to a universal user ID (lookup table makes sense to me).

Since you have a website, an email address and multiple channels I would say the assumption is that **users first registered on the web site**. Each user has a unique email address and obtains an account secured by username/password, as well as a unique secret token.

When chatting on browser (ie Rasa WebChat) you can initialise the plugin with custom parameters (ie userId=1 or token=X), in this case the chat session is assigned to the given user id.

When using Telegram (or other messenger application) I would (at the very first access) ask the user if he/she has already registered. If yes then I would ask the token: this can be used to perform the map and link this Telegram user to the universal user Id. Same approach for other channels.

Depending on your needs you might need to deal with anonymous access (users don't provide the token) or maybe you want to provide a different token for each channel (more secure, but requires more work and an easy way to explain this to users).

Finally something to look at (I haven't tried myself) is the possibility to provide in the web site the option to open Telegram (or others) passing an extra parameter, which would allow you to perform the mapping. I don't know if this is possible, but it would simplify this process for your end users. Or the other way around: the users in Telegram could be provided with a link which opens the website, where they can login and be recognised.

Comment: Thanks Beppe for interesting points. Telegram: following your extra-param suggestion, I could insert the e-mail address (as a sort of "UUID", at least in the web app) in the  website, as TG connection link, allowing the user to connect him to the TG channell thttps://telegram.me/myBot?start=giorgio.robino@blabla.it see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42457831/1786393

Comment: and about RASA WebChat I guess I could also pass the user email as sender_id. I have to deepen how to